# Check all files sizes in a path (C++)

Tags: c++, size

I'm trying to loop so that my program can get the weight of all files in a folder, and if the weight of any of these is equal to X, it will do an action, I need to know how I can loop like this, and i have a func to know whats the file size

```cpp
std::ifstream::pos_type filesize(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary);
    return in.tellg();
}
```

Comment: C++17: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size . `<filesystem>` will also let you iterate over a directory. The method you're showing isn't accurate.

Comment: im trying do this... if have a file with X size in a certain path, will do a function, else, do nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short example program that demonstrates how to use C++17's `<filesystem>` library to iterate over a directory. If your compiler is fairly up-to-date, it should support C++17 without issue.

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  namespace fs = std::filesystem;

  fs::path pwd("");  // Current directory program was executed from
  pwd = fs::absolute(pwd);

  for (auto& i : fs::directory_iterator(pwd)) {
    try {
      if (fs::file_size(i.path()) / 1024 > 2048) {
        std::cout << i.path() << " is larger than 2MB\n";
      }
    } catch (fs::filesystem_error& e) {
      std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
  }
}
```

This was the contents of the directory:

```
.
├── a.out
├── fiveKB
├── fourMB
├── main.cpp
└── oneMB

0 directories, 5 files
```

And information about the files:

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 user  staff   224B Jul 29 22:11 ./
drwxr-xr-x  13 user  staff   416B Jul 29 21:59 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff    47K Jul 29 22:10 a.out*
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff   5.0K Jul 29 21:58 fiveKB
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff   4.0M Jul 29 21:59 fourMB
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff   450B Jul 29 22:11 main.cpp
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff   1.0M Jul 29 21:59 oneMB
```

And finally, the output:
`"/Users/user/Documents/tmp/test/fourMB" is larger than 2MB`